# Android how to load drawable images to imageview efficiently

Tags: android, performance, android-imageview, android-drawable

I need to load a bunch of images on the drawable folder to a list of imageview. I'm getting an java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 17280012 byte allocation with 8452164 free bytes and 8MB until OOM error.

Here's the an array file that lists all image names in the drawable folder that needs to be loaded.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <resources>
<string-array name="photo_frames">
    <item>pf1</item>
    <item>pf2</item>
    <item>pf3</item>
    <item>pf4</item>
    <item>pf5</item>
    <item>pf6</item>
    <item>pf7</item>
    <item>pf8</item>
    <item>pf9</item>
    <item>pf10</item>
    <item>pf11</item>
    <item>pf12</item>
     </string-array>
 </resources>
```

Here's the code for the listAdapter to load the image, photoFrames is an array that holds the image names.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        //Layout inflate for list item
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.list_item_photo_frames, null);
    }

    ImageView imgPhotoFrames = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_photo_frames);
    imgPhotoFrames.setImageResource(mContext.getResources().getIdentifier(photoFrames[position], "drawable", mContext.getPackageName()));


    return convertView;
}
```

If I have a few images it loads fine, but it is kind of lag. When there are more images to be loaded to imageView, then it return an error, Thanks.

Comment: use imageloading library like picasso, glide etc.

Comment: Try to use RecyclerView and use some third party library like [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) to load images.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

17280012 bytes is the equivalent of a 2078 x 2078 pixel image. **This is larger than the resolution of most device screens.** You should be loading 0-1 of these images at a time, not 12 of them.

If your images have a high resolution like that, lower their resolution.

If your images have a lower resolution already, but you put them in `res/drawable/`, either move them to `res/drawable-nodpi/` or plan on creating different editions of the drawables for different densities. No bitmaps belong in `res/drawable/`, as that is just a synonym for `res/drawable-mdpi/`, and so Android will resample the images on higher-density screens.

Comment: Thanks, the largest of the image is 1200x800, maybe I should create thumbnails for them and load the thumbnails.

Comment: @Julia check this out for a lower level understanding: https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/index.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use an array of id's for drawables

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <integer-array name="photo_frames">
        <item>@drawable/pf1</item>
        <item>@drawable/pf2</item>
        .....
    </integer-array>
</resources>
```

and to load them you can use `TypedArray`

```
// load array into CONSTRUCTOR
TypedArray photoFrameArray = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.photo_frames);

// or set you ImageView's resource to the id
imgPhotoFrames.setImageResource(photoFrameArray.getResourceId(position, R.drawable.default_drawable));
```

Keep in mind that you should recycle array

```
photoFrameArray.recycle();
```

Also, if you have very large images (1000x1000 px), you will have memory problems

In order to load large images, i recommend you to use `Picasso`. You can load large drawables into your `ImageView`

Answer (score 0):

It depends how big your Imageis, Android seems to allocate a little more space than the size of the image when you read the size on your computer. So...

- You could just use a smaller image.
- Google have actually published a guide on avoiding OutOfMemoryErrors
  [here](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) which will help a lot, though I had to use a smaller image size
  as well.
- One method that will almost definitely work is to set
  [android:largeHeap="true"](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#AndroidManifestApplication_largeHeap) in your manifest, between your application
  tags. This will increase your heap size, but may make your app lag a
  little.
- You can try using Glide, the Google recommended lib to load images

Maybe for you, a combination of these ideas will work.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a caching mechanism.

Here's one example that might give you an idea about using image caching:

```
public class FlowerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Flower> {

    private Context context;
    private List<Flower> flowerList;

    //set the LRU (Least Recently Used) object as an image cache
    private LruCache<Integer,Bitmap> imageCache;

    public FlowerAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Flower> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.flowerList = objects;

        //initialize the cache in the constructor
        //determine the maximum amount of memory of the device
        final int maxMemory = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory());
        //set the cache size to be one-eight of the maximum memory
//      final int cacheSize = maxMemory/9999999; //using this number you can see the effects
        final int cacheSize = maxMemory/8; //real-life situation
        //create the image cache (instantiate it)
        imageCache = new LruCache<>(cacheSize);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = 
                (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_flower, parent, false);

        //Display flower name in the TextView widget
        Flower flower = flowerList.get(position);
        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv.setText(flower.getName());

        //Display flower photo in ImageView widget
        //verify if the flower exists in cache
        Bitmap bitmap = imageCache.get(flower.getProductId());
        if (bitmap != null) {
            ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
        else {
            FlowerAndView container = new FlowerAndView();
            container.flower = flower;
            container.view = view;

            ImageLoader loader = new ImageLoader();
            loader.execute(container);
        }


        return view;
    }

    class FlowerAndView {
        public Flower flower;
        public View view;
        public Bitmap bitmap;
    }

    private class ImageLoader extends AsyncTask<FlowerAndView, Void, FlowerAndView> {

        @Override
        protected FlowerAndView doInBackground(FlowerAndView... params) {

            FlowerAndView container = params[0];
            Flower flower = container.flower;

            try {
                String imageUrl = MainActivity.PHOTOS_BASE_URL + flower.getPhoto();
                InputStream in = (InputStream) new URL(imageUrl).getContent();
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                flower.setBitmap(bitmap);
                in.close();
                container.bitmap = bitmap;
                return container;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(FlowerAndView result) {
            ImageView image = (ImageView) result.view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            image.setImageBitmap(result.bitmap);
//          result.flower.setBitmap(result.bitmap);
            //put the image in the cache
            imageCache.put(result.flower.getProductId(),result.bitmap);
        }

    }

}
```